# Update attributes and return a new copy of the same class

Tags: python

```
class Main(object):

    def __init__(self,  config):
        selt.attributes = config

    def return_new_copy(self, additional_attributes):
        addtional_attributes.update(self.attributes)
        return Main(additional_attributes)
```

I want to update the instance attributes and return a new instance of the same class. I guess I am trying to find out if the above code is Pythonic or if it's a dirty approach. I can't use classmethod for several reasons not mentioned here. Is there another recommended approach.

Comment: Why not just update them? I.e. `m1 = Main({'a': 1}); m2 = Main({'b': 2}); m2.attributes.update(m1.attributes)`. Regarding your approach I'd use `type(self)` instead of `Main` but apart from that it's fine. You could also define `+` operator by defining `__add__` then you can use `m1 = Main({'a': 1}); m2 = m1 + {'b': 2}`.

Comment: you can use copy module for deepcopy and return that instance.

Comment: Do you want the original `Main` instance and the new one to share attribute values or should it get a copy of them? AFAIK, there's nothing particularly "unpythonic" about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return_new_copy` modifies the parameter passed in which is probably undesirable.  It also overrides in the wrong direction (giving precedence to `self.attributes`)

I'd write it as follows:

```
def return_new_copy(self, additional_attributes):
     # python<3.5 if there are only string keys:
     #     attributes = dict(self.attributes, **additional_attributes)
     # python<3.5 if there are non-string keys:
     #     attributes = self.attributes.copy()
     #     attributes.update(additional_attributes)
     # python3.5+
     attributes = {**self.attributes, **additional_attributes}
     return type(self)(attributes)
```

A few subtleties:
- I make sure to copy both the input attributes and the self attributes
- I merge the additional attributes on top of the self attributes

If you're looking for something to do this automatically, you might want to check out [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

For example:

```
>>> C = collections.namedtuple('C', ('a', 'b'))
>>> x = C(1, 2)
>>> x
C(a=1, b=2)
>>> y = x._replace(b=3)
>>> y
C(a=1, b=3)
>>> x
C(a=1, b=2)
```